# I Have a problem with my Google Authentication, displaying the error 'pop-up closed by user'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, google-authentication

I am trying to implement Google authentication in my web application, but I keep getting an error.
I generated my token on the Google Console Website, but when I try to sign in I get the error: "popup_closed_by_user", when in the console I should have seen the credentials of the google account. Below is the code for the authentication:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Avatar, Button, Paper, Grid, Typography, Container, TextField} from '@material-ui/core';
import {GoogleLogin} from 'react-google-login';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import useStyles from './styles';
import Input from './Input';
import Icon from './icon';

const Auth=()=>{
    const classes=useStyles();
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] =useState(false);
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);

    const handleShowPassword=()=>setShowPassword((prevShowPassword)=> !prevShowPassword);

    const handleSubmit=()=>{

    };

    const handleChange=()=>{

    };

    const switchMode=()=>{
        setIsSignup((prevIsSignUp)=> !prevIsSignUp);
        handleShowPassword(false);
    };




    const googleSuccess=async (res)=>{
        console.log(res);
    };

    const googleFailure=(error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try Again Later.");
    };

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={3}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                <LockOutlinedIcon/>
            </Avatar>
            <Typography variant="h5">{isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}</Typography>
            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {
                        isSignup && (
                            <>
                       
                            <Input name="firstName" label="First Name" handleChange={handleChange} autoFocus half/>
                            <Input name="lastName" label="Last Name" handleChange={handleChange} half/>
                        
                            </>
                    )}
                    <Input name="email" label="Email Address" handleChange={handleChange} type="email"/>
                    <Input name="password" label="Password" handleChange={handleChange} type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"} handleShowPassword={handleShowPassword}/>
                    {
                        isSignup && <Input name="confirmPassword" label="Repeat Password" handleChange={handleChange} type="password"/>
                    }
                </Grid>
                <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.submit}>
                {isSignup ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'}
                 </Button>
                <GoogleLogin
                    clientId=""
                    render={(renderProps)=>(
                        <Button
                        className={classes.googleButton}
                        color="primary"
                        fullWidth
                        onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                        disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                        startIcon={<Icon/>}
                        variant="contained"
                        >
                            Google Sign In
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    onSuccess={googleSuccess}
                    onFailure={googleFailure}
                    cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
                />
                <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
                <Grid item>
                    <Button onClick={switchMode}>
                        {isSignup ? 'Already have an account? Sign In' : "Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                    
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
        </Paper>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Auth
```

I have generated the token and put it in my code, but I deleted it for this post and I also cleared my cache and unchecked the "Block third-party cookies button" in my browser settings.
Could you help me?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: I added all the relevant code